# LSTM プログラムの再現性が担保できない

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

現在LSTMで研究を行っているのですが、実行毎に結果が異なってしまい再現性が担保できておりません。
ネットで調べた情報を用いていろいろ試してみましたが、解決には至りませんでした。
下記にコードを掲載いたしますので、コードの具体例等を用いて解決策をご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'                                    #警告表示の解除
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder                              #sklearnライブラリに含まれるLabelEncoderクラスをインポートしている(LabelEncoderは数値や文字列で表されたラベルを(0~ラベル種類数-1)までの数値に変換する)
from keras.utils import np_utils
import pandas as pd                                                         #データ解析を容易にするためのモジュール pdという名前でインポートしている
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer                              #Kerasライブラリに含まれるTokenizerクラスをインポートしている(Tokenizerは文章のベクトル化に必要)
from keras.utils import pad_sequences                                       #Kerasライブラリに含まれるsequenceクラスとインポートしている(sequenceは異なる長さのテンソルの末尾を0埋めして長さを揃えてくれる)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split                        #sklearnライブラリに含まれるtrain_test_splitクラスをインポートしている(train_test_splitはデータをテストと訓練に二分割する)
from keras.models import Sequential                                         #kerasライブラリに含まれるSequentialクラスをインポートしている(Sequentialは入力と出力が一つずつのニューラルネットワーク)
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM                             #kerasライブラリに含まれるDense, Embedding, LSTMクラスをインポートしている(後日調べる)
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping                                   #kerasライブラリに含まれるEarlyStoppingクラスをインポートしている(EarlyStoppingは過学習を引き起こす前に学習を止めてくれる)
from keras.layers import Dropout                                            #kerasライブラリに含まれるDropoutクラスをインポートしている(Dropoutは過学習を抑制してくれる理論は知らん)
from keras.backend import clear_session                                     #kerasライブラリに含まれるclear_sessionクラスをインポートしている(clear_sessionは識別子をリセットする)
from keras.models import Sequential                                         #kerasライブラリに含まれるSequentialクラスをインポートしている(clear_sessionは識別子をリセットする)
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, LSTM                   #
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam                                #tensorflowライブラリに含まれるAdamクラスをインポートしている()
import optuna                                                               #
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier                     #kerasライブラリに含まれるKerasClassifierクラスをインポートしている()
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

with open("all_api_call.txt") as f:                                    
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
data = pd.DataFrame()                                                       #データフレームの作成(データフレームは表形式のデータになる)
data['feature'] = content

max_words = 800                                                             #トークン化するAPIの総数を定義
max_len = 100
X = data['feature']

"""トークン化,シーケンス番号への変換"""
#トークン化...文章を単語や文字列単語に分割すること(今回はAPI名ごとに分割)
#シーケンス番号...機械学習で扱いやすい数値
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)                                  #Tokenizerのインスタンスを作成・num_wordsは学習させたい単語の種数を入れる
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)                                                   #XをAPI名ごと分割し,それぞれに番号を与える(トークン化)・(例)'getasynckeystate': 1, 'ntdelayexecution': 2, 'ntclose': 3...
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)                                         #API名をシーケンス番号に変換する
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_len, truncating='post')                     #シーケンスの設定(maxlenはシーケンスの最大値,truncatingはmaxlen以上のシーケンスを前後どちらで切り詰めるか"post"は末尾(この場合は101回目以降がカットされる))
#print(tokenizer.word_index)
#print(X)

"""シーケンス番号とAPI名称の対応状況について(補足)"""
#トークン化の際に与えた番号とシーケンス番号が一致している
#上記対応付けを行うことでLSTMを使用して訓練を可能にしている


"""正解ラベルの読み込み"""
with open("labels.csv") as f:
    label_data = f.readlines()

"""正解ラベルの整形"""
label_data = [x.strip() for x in label_data]
data["labels"] = label_data

"""検出器の作成(今回はVirusとラベリングされている物を検出する)"""
y = data["labels"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == "Backdoor.Win32.Androm" else 0)                #条件定義(applyはデータフレームの各行に条件を適応する)

"""訓練データとテストデータに分割"""
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15)   #テストデータが15%,訓練が85%で分割


"""ニューラルネットワークの各層について(補足)"""
#埋め込み層...整数でエンコードされた単語ベクトルを受け取り,各単語のインデックスに対する分散表現を算出する
#分散表現...単語を低次元の実数値ベクトルで表す表現(他の方法では単語の並び順や順序を維持できない)
#LSTM層...前層からの出力である分散表現を受け取り,それをもとに訓練を行う
#出力層...予測値を出力する




"""LSTMを用いてモデル準備"""
def malware_model():
    model = Sequential()                                                    #Sequential宣言
    model.add(Embedding(max_words, 300, input_length=max_len))              #整数でエンコードされた単語(API名)ベクトルを受け取り,各単語のインデックスに対する分散表現を算出する
    model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    return model

"""モデルを有効化して訓練"""
model = malware_model()
model.summary()                                                              #モデルの要約を出力する
model.compile(                                                               #訓練に関する設定を行う
    loss='binary_crossentropy',                                              #損失関数に二値交差エントロピーを指定
    optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy']                                    #最適化アルゴリズムにAdamを指定
    )
#損失関数...正解値と算出した予測値のズレを求めるのに用いる
#二値交差エントロピー...2つの確立分布がどれくらい離れているかを表す指標
#最適化アルゴリズム...損失を0にすることを目的としたもの
#Adam...わからん

history = model.fit(                                                        #訓練の実行(history = model.fit(...)は固定)
    X_train,
    y_train, 
    batch_size=64,                                                          #サブセット分ける(サイズは2のn乗から決める)
    epochs=10,                                                              #学習する回数を設定(試しながら決める)
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),                                       #検証するデータを引数として渡す
    verbose=1                                                               #結果をエポックごとのログがプログレスバーの進行状況とともに表示
    )
```

Comment: 「ネットで調べた情報を用いていろいろ試してみましたが、解決には至りませんでした。」の”調べた情報””いろいろ試してみました”について具体的に書かれると回答がつきやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: このサイトは、質問者さんの役に立つことももちろんですが、情報を蓄積してその他の多くの方にも役に立つ Q&A 集を作成することも大きな目的です。
質問者さんが既に不要となった質問でも、自由に削除することはできません。
ご了承下さい。このサイトの仕組みなどについて不明な点は[メタサイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)でご質問下さい。
メタサイトに関しては[『「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？ 』](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)をご覧下さい。

Comment: 質問を自分で終了する機能はありません。擬似的に終了したい場合は、[質問を自分から終了したい場合には?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2634/)にある方法をとってください。ただし、プラス票の回答がある質問は削除が出来ませんので、1か3の方法を取ってください。

Answer (score 4):

乱数の初期化が主な原因と思いますので、未テストですが次のようにシード値を固定すれば良いのではないかと思います。

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

SEED = 42 
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=SEED)

study = optuna.create_study(sampler=optuna.samplers.RandomSampler(seed=SEED))
```

Comment: ご提示いただいたプログラムで結果を固定することができました!!